# two complex polynomials with equal modulus on a parabola

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Are there any two complex polynomials $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ with the same degree, such that their modulus is equal on the  parabola $y=x^2$ but they are not a  constant  multiple of each other? in other words, can we have $|p(x+ix^2)|=|q(x+ix^2)|$ for two complex polynomials $p$ and $q$ for all real $x$, where $p\not=q.$

The above quesion is equivalent to the following:
is there any rational complex fuction sending the parabola $y=x^2$ to the unit circle?

Comment: Erm. Isn't it "moduli"?

Comment: maybe you should include that they have leading coefficient $1$.

Answer (score 5):

There is no nonconstant rational function taking the parabola to the unit circle. **Proof:** Consider any rational function of one complex variable. It extends to a smooth map $\phi: \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$. Let $\gamma$ be the closure of the parabola; it is a closed curve in $\mathbb{CP}^1$. We claim that $\phi(\gamma)$ is not smooth and, in particular, is not the unit circle.

Let's first see what $\gamma$ looks like near $\infty$. Geometrically, the two branches of the parabola come into $\infty$ in the same direction, so $\gamma$ has a cusp at $\infty$. If you don't trust your geometric intuition, here is a direct computation. Let $u+iv$ be a coordinate near $\infty$, so $x+iy = (u+iv)^{-1} = u/(u^2+v^2) - i v/(u^2+v^2)$. So the equation of $\gamma$ is 
$$\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2} = \left( \frac{u}{u^2+v^2} \right)^2$$
or, clearing denominators,
$$(u^2+v^2) v + u^2 =0$$
This cubic has a cusp at $(0,0)$, as shown in the figure below.

[image]   [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/cusp.png)

Now, let $e$ be the order of branching of $\phi$ at $\infty$. So $\phi$ multiplies angles by the integer $e$. We see that the curve $\phi(\gamma)$ will also come into $\phi(\infty)$ in the same direction from both sides. In particular, $\phi(\gamma)$ is not smooth at $\phi(\infty)$, and cannot be the unit circle.

Comment: It seems true, but I could not follow. The one below seems to use the same idea (Michael's solution)

Comment: Would it help if I linked you to the wikipedia entry for Riemmann sphere? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Comment: Can you explain what order of branching is, or intrudude a reference for that? Do you suggest that a smooth function should preserve the angles?

Comment: Almost. Let $f$ be a nonconstant analytic function defined near a point $z_0$. Change variables so that $z_0 = f(z_0) = 0$. So $f = c_e z^e + c_{e+1} z^{e+1} + \cdots$, for some positive integer $e$ and some nonzero $c_e$. If $e=1$, then $f$ preserves angles near $z_0$. In general, $f$ multiplies angles by a factor of $e$ at $z_0$. This $e$ is the order I am referring to.

Answer (score 2):

If P and Q have the same degree and leading coefficient, then P/Q converges to 1 at infinity. Consequently, the function
$$g(w)=\log(P(1/w)/Q(1/w))$$
has a single valued branch near the origin. The real part of g would have to be zero on the curve $(u^2+v^2)v=-u^2$, where $w=u+iv$. This curve has a cusp at the origin, so it cannot be part of the zero set of a harmonic function.

Comment: Why can't a curve with a cusp at origin be the zero set of a harmonic function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take $P$ and $Q=e^{it}P$.